# vb 6 error in executing stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vb6, xampp, runtime-error

I have a vb 6 program that calls stored procedure residing in MYSQL Database. When I tried to test this one in two different computers, it works in computer1 but has error in computer2.

These computers have:

- same php and mysql versions (xampp)
- same odbc 3.51 driver
- same stored procedures
- same code
- both windows 7 32-bit os

This is the error:

```
Run-time error -2147217900(80040e14)
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld 5.1.41] You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to     
use '{ call Selectproducts}' at line 1.
```

The 'selectproducts' there is the name of my stored procedure. I've searched this on google but nothing has the same with this error.

Can you please help me with this one? I really don't know what's the problem of my computer2.

SP code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `selectproducts`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectproducts`()
begin
select * from products;
end
```

Comment: Post a code excerpt and/or the actual SQL command being tried.

Comment: I've updated my post and posted the sp code.

Comment: have you tried performing the query with mysql command line option in both computers?

Comment: @JW.: how come? As i have said, it's working on another computer. Same everything, the code, the way how it is called.

Comment: Set up mysql to log all queries and then compare the logged query from the version that fails to the logged query from the version that succeeds. Then you will at least know the specific difference that is causing the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a virus. Reinstall your xampp, VB6 , and Driver. Then test again and compare the log files of computer1 with computer2. Be sure to look closely to the code if everything is the same. Don't forget to check your stored procedures carefully.

Comment: WOW!GREAT!Thanks!Everything wen well.Cheers!